# Which word best describes a story made up of analogies, metaphors and perhaps parables?

Tags: metaphors, analogy, story

Which word (if any) best describes a complete story that is made up of analogies, metaphors and possibly some parables?

For example, if I was writing a story about someone's life journey, but writing it as if it was a boat on a river that started as a small trickle, then gained momentum and energy, had periods of calm, then encountered rough waters etc.  Would that be an analogy? Would the fact it is a story be too much for an analogy?  I think of an analogy more like a one-liner or a sentence at most.

I don't think parable would fit.  A parable appears to require a moral to the story.  My story may not have a moral to it.  Also I don't think a metaphor is broad enough.  Perhaps a sustained metaphor?

Please help..

Comment: Perhaps an **allegory**?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory

Comment: On ELU, 'metaphor' is usually used with the 'sustained/extended metaphor' sense. Look up 'the container metaphor', 'the _up-is-good_ metaphor'. For an intelligent audience, 'metaphor' works well. 'Analogy' sounds rather clinical.  'Allegory' is not incorrect, but sounds dated. And as for 'parable' ....

Comment: The "story analogy" you refer to was made famous by a particular Classical Era poet (Roman, possibly Greek), who popularized it. But I can't remember who it was, and my Google-Fu currently isn't helping me. Still looking, but if anyone knows who I'm referring to, release me from my agony! I even still remember the example we discussed in class, how he described the story of a weeping mother to a tigress who has lost her cubs and compulsively kept looking for them.

Comment: Found the poet (Ovid, the tigress example is from Metamorphoses), but there seems to be no established name relating to his use of analogy/metaphor/allegory. We always referred to it in class as an "Ovidian allegory" and were told that it's a well-establish literary device, but I'm not finding any resources that confirm this.

Comment: Thank you, both Edwin and Flater.  Flater, I was unaware of the 'Ovidian allegory' and will investigate it further.